# Javascript Help about "document.getElementById" please

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function changeDate(option) {
            var selectList = document.getElementById("catProdAttributeItem");
            if (option == 0) {
                selectList.selectedIndex++;
            } else if (option == 1 && selectList.selectedIndex > 0) {
                selectList.selectedIndex--;
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src="img1.jpg" onclick="changeDate(0)">
        <img src="img2.jpg" onclick="changeDate(1)">
        <select id="pa_colour" name="attribute_pa_colour">
            <option value="">Choose an option…</option>
            <option value="black" class="active">Black</option>
            <option value="blue" class="active">Blue</option>
            <option value="red" class="active">Red</option>
            <option value="white" class="active">White</option>
        </select>
        <div id="catProdAttributeItem">
            <select>
                <option id="1">One</option>
                <option id="2">Two</option>
                <option id="3">three</option>
                <option id="4">Four</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this code what I want to do is when the user clicks an image, the select option value will change.

If the `<select id="list">` select has an id it will work fine, but in my case, the select option has no id, but before the select there is a class `"catProdAttributeItem"`. 
How do I make it work with document.getElementById and select option?

Comment: Why can't you just assign an id to the select and then get the selected value?

Comment: What do you mean by "before the select"? Is it a sibling, or a parent? Post the actual HTML you're working with instead of some HTML that doesn't represent the problem.

Comment: I removed the jQuery tag--jQuery makes this kind of thing trivial, but you're specifically asking for a native JavaScript approach.

Comment: @Jonathan - Im using Buiness Catalyst. in that i dont have access to the source code of the ecommerce functions. so that why i need to do that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select element is the child of Div, so you need to access the child element. For that,use following :

```
var selectList = document.getElementById("catProdAttributeItem").children[0];
```

Here is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/spdX3/

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I could imagine it is because your fiddle html is invalid.

Comment: @TJ : fiddle html is html given above in question. I havn't modified it at my own.

Answer (score 0):

Since the select element is within the catProdAttributeItem div, you can select it using the childNodes property

```
var selectList = document.getElementById("catProdAttributeItem").childNodes[0];
```

Rest of the code should work as it is.